# Create a timeline with PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, timeline

I am starting a project with Python and PyQt5. I would like to have a timeline widget like that

[image]

So in the futur I would like each rectangle to be a button, but my main issue at the moment is to make the timeline stick to the width of my window.

At the moment, my timeline inherits from QFrame, and each rectangle is a QFrame too. So is it a good way to do it ? Is there a better way to do it ?

Here is what I tried :

Main.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor
from Timeline import *
from Job import *

class FreelanceAssistant(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.resize(1080, 720)
        self.move(300, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle("Freelance Assistant")
        p = self.palette()
        p.setColor(self.backgroundRole(), QColor(32, 47, 60))
        self.setPalette(p)

        timeline = Timeline(self)

        timeline.addJob(Job(QDate(2017, 11, 21), QDate(2018, 1, 12), "Red Knuckles", 200, QColor(140, 67, 67)))
        timeline.addJob(Job(QDate(2018, 1, 15), QDate(2018, 1, 26), "ETC", 200, QColor(67, 76, 140)))

        window_layout= QVBoxLayout()
        print(self.getContentsMargins())
        self.setLayout(window_layout)
        window_layout.addWidget(timeline)

        self.show()

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = FreelanceAssistant()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Timeline.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QDate
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFrame, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor

class Timeline(QFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.jobs_number = 0

        self.setGeometry(0, 0, parent.width(), 200)
        self.setStyleSheet("QWidget { background-color: %s }" %  QColor(26, 36, 45).name())

        self.__invoice_pos = self.height() * 0.5
        self.__invoice_height = 13
        self.__job_top_pos = self.height() * 0.5 + self.__invoice_height
        self.__job_height = (self.height() - self.__job_top_pos)/2
        self.__job_bottom_pos = self.__job_top_pos + self.__job_height

        line1 = QFrame(parent)
        line1.setGeometry(0, self.height() * 0.5, self.width(), 1)
        line1.setStyleSheet("QWidget { background-color: %s }" %  QColor(66, 76, 85).name())

        line2 = QFrame(parent)
        line2.setGeometry(0, self.height(), self.width(), 1)
        line2.setStyleSheet("QWidget { background-color: %s }" %  QColor(66, 76, 85).name())

        self.__starts_on = QDate.currentDate().addMonths(-1)
        self.__ends_on = QDate.currentDate().addMonths(5)
        self.__days_range = self.__starts_on.daysTo(self.__ends_on)

        current_year = QLabel(str(self.__starts_on.year()), parent)
        current_year.move(5, self.height() + 5)
        current_year.setStyleSheet("QWidget { color: %s }" %  QColor(245, 245, 245).name())

        for year in range(self.__starts_on.year() + 1, self.__ends_on.year() + 1):
            days_to_new_year = self.__starts_on.daysTo(QDate(year, 1, 1))
            new_year_line_pos = days_to_new_year/self.__days_range * self.width()

            new_year_line = QFrame(parent)
            new_year_line.setGeometry(int(new_year_line_pos), 0, 1, self.height() + 20)
            new_year_line.setStyleSheet("QWidget { background-color: %s }" %  QColor(245, 245, 245).name())

            current_year = QLabel(str(year), parent)
            current_year.move(int(new_year_line_pos) + 5, self.height() + 5)
            current_year.setStyleSheet("QWidget { color: %s }" %  QColor(245, 245, 245).name())

        invoice_start = QDate(2017, 11, 21)
        invoice_end = QDate(2017, 12, 13)

        invoice_start_pos = self.__starts_on.daysTo(invoice_start)/self.__days_range * self.width()
        invoice_width = invoice_start.daysTo(invoice_end)/self.__days_range * self.width()

        invoice_frame = QFrame(self)
        invoice_frame.setGeometry(invoice_start_pos, self.__invoice_pos, invoice_width, self.__invoice_height)
        invoice_frame.setStyleSheet("QWidget { background-color: %s }" %  QColor(50, 200, 50).name())

        invoice_end_date = QLabel(invoice_end.toString("dd MMM"), invoice_frame)
        invoice_end_date.move(invoice_frame.width() - 40, 0)
        invoice_end_date.setStyleSheet("QWidget { color: %s }" %  QColor(0, 0, 0).name())

    def addJob(self, job):
        start_pos = self.__starts_on.daysTo(job.starts_on)/self.__days_range * self.width()
        width = job.days_range/self.__days_range * self.width()

        job_frame = QFrame(self)
        if self.jobs_number % 2 == 0:
            job_frame.setGeometry(start_pos, self.__job_bottom_pos, width, self.__job_height)
        else:
            job_frame.setGeometry(start_pos, self.__job_top_pos, width, self.__job_height)
        job_frame.setStyleSheet("QWidget { background-color:" + job.color.name() + " } QWidget:hover{background-color: " + job.color.darker(125).name() + "}")

        company_name = QLabel(job.company, job_frame)
        company_name.move(5, 5)
        company_name.setStyleSheet("QWidget { color: %s }" %  QColor(245, 245, 245).name())

        start_date = QLabel(job.starts_on.toString("dd MMM"), job_frame)
        start_date.move(5, job_frame.height() - 20)
        start_date.setStyleSheet("QWidget { color: %s }" %  QColor(245, 245, 245).name())

        end_date = QLabel(job.ends_on.toString("dd MMM"), job_frame)
        end_date.move(job_frame.width() - 40, job_frame.height() - 20)
        end_date.setStyleSheet("QWidget { color: %s }" %  QColor(245, 245, 245).name())

        self.jobs_number += 1
```

Job.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QDate
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor

class Job():
    def __init__(self, start, end, company, rate, color):
        self.starts_on = start
        self.ends_on = end
        self.company = company
        self.rate = rate
        self.color = color
        self.days_range = self.starts_on.daysTo(self.ends_on)
```

Comment: Show the code you have tried, and we will try to help you.

Comment: If you want us to help you, you must provide a [mcve]

Comment: Sorry for that, I updated with what I tried

Comment: What are the drawbacks with your implementation?

Comment: I just want the timeline to resize when I resize the window, but I don't know how to update my widget when that happens

Comment: Do you want the horizontal lines to stretch when the width of the window changes? And the vertical lines have to change?

Comment: No just horizontaly

Comment: You might want to consider using existing libraries to make the timeline. Thay way you don't have to deal with issues like this. I'm sure pyqtgraph could be adapted and I'm sure there are other options too.

Comment: Ah ok, I'll have a look, and by the way I have an inner border between my window borders and my timeline, I think it is due to my QVBoxLayout, do you have an idea on how to remove it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution for this case is to overwrite the `resizeEvent()` method, that method is called every time the widget resizes, so we take advantage of that method to change the width of `line1` and `line2`, but so that these `QLabel` can be accessed from that method must be members of the class, for this you must change `line1` and `line2` to `self.line1` and `self.line2`:

```
class Timeline(QFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

        [...]

        self.line1 = QFrame(self)
        self.line1.setGeometry(0, self.height() * 0.5, self.width(), 1)
        self.line1.setStyleSheet("QWidget { background-color: %s }" %  QColor(66, 76, 85).name())

        self.line2 = QFrame(self)
        self.line2.setGeometry(0, self.height(), self.width(), 1)
        self.line2.setStyleSheet("QWidget { background-color: %s }" %  QColor(66, 76, 85).name())

        [...]

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        for line in [self.line1, self.line2]:
            line.resize(self.width(), line.size().height())
        QFrame.resizeEvent(self, event)
```